# Retrieving value from a bootstrap dropdownlist not working

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down list from a bootsrap theme but I cant seem to retrieve the value from it with jQuery.

```
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Type</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="btn-group m-r">
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="dropdown-label">Offices</span> 
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul  id="selType" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
                          <li class="active"><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-r" value="Offices">Offices</a></li>
                          <li class=""><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-r" value="Warehousing">Warehousing</a></li>
                          <li class=""><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-r" value="Retail">Retail</a></li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

The active class indicates the selected value. but does not seem to work when i do stuff like this.

```
var Type = $('ul#selType li.selected').text();
var Type = $('ul li.active a input').text();
var Type = $('#selType li.active').find('input').text();
var Type = $('ul li.selected a input:radio').val();
var Type = $('ul li.active a input').text();
```

I am new to this so I might be missing something so any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the above answers would require to click. So I decided to give my button an id and then get the value of the inner span tag of that button, it will always be the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
var Type = $('ul#selType li.selected').text();
```

is bad usage. When there is a id always select with just id. Select with by using `#selType` not `ul#selType`

And for your question you can get radio button selection value by using:

```
$('input[name=d-s-r]:checked').val();
```

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thanks for the quick reply. I decided to go with another route but I appreciate the the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this (click on button to allert):

```js
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function getvalue(){
var type = $('#selType input:checked').val();
if (typeof type ==='undefined'){
alert("Please select an option!");
}
else{
    alert (type);
}
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Type</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="btn-group m-r">
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="dropdown-label">Offices</span> 
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul  id="selType" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
                          <li class="active"><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-r" value="Offices">Offices</a></li>
                          <li class=""><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-r" value="Warehousing">Warehousing</a></li>
                          <li class=""><a href="#"><input type="radio" name="d-s-r" value="Retail">Retail</a></li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I tried your code but the problem was that the user would not always click and I didn't want too add please select as a item to dropdown. But I got it working I decided to just retrieve the value from the span tag. It is set when page loads so no need for clicking and it updates when you select a new item so it will always have the correct value. But thanks anyway.